# editing the build definition in VS15

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I am trying to resolve a MSBuild error in a VS .Net application by editing the build definition. However, when I enter team explorer, my menu looks like this[image]

As you can see there is no build option, nor a team foundation server. (I am not sure if we are using one.
Therefore, my issue is figuring out how to open the menu for the build definition. It does not appear if searched in quick launch and the search work items searchbar is not working for some reason. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think it depends how you checked out the code, and if you're connected to TFS. Have a play with the Plug icon, there's probably something.

Comment: We are not using tfs

Comment: Then you won't get build definition in that screen panel. the Build's panel is part of TFS. If you want to edit your project's build settings you would do it from the Project Properties

Comment: Do you know where within project properties? I do not see the option

Comment: You might need to update the question with more information about the MSBuild errors, it feels a bit like an X/Y problem at the moment. Someone should be able to help with the build errors, if they knew what they were.

Comment: Okay thank you for your help! I will update with the build errors when I have a second to rerun the solution

Answer (score 1):

> editing the build definition in VS15

If I understand you correctly, you have encountered a MSBuild error, and you want to resolve this issue by build definition, but the Builds on the Team Explorer is part of TFS rather than MSBuild. If you want to see the Builds panel on the Team Explorer, you just need to connect to the TFS server, then you will see it:

[image]

Besides, if you want to resolve your MSBuild error, you can get the error info from the Output window, and you can check more detail info by change the output verbosity (Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->MSBuild project build output verbosity). If you could not resolve this issue, you can submit a new post with that MSBuild error log and some other info that you think is related to this issue. More community members on this forum may further look at your issue and provide more suggestions.